# Apollo Playground on remote server

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

When I install the Apollo Server 2 dependencies, follow the quickstart, and spin up a local server - I see the GraphQL Playground on local host

However, when I deploy the same exact code to a remote server, and visit the url, I see "GET query missing."

If I visit the url and supply a query as a parameter - e.g. https://example.com?query={books{title author}} - then I do see relevant results (as json)

What is causing the difference between seeing the playground view vs. just the raw api "view" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably what is happening is that when you deploy your code then the `NODE_ENV` is changed to `production` and when that happens `Graphql Playground` is disabled,
you can find more about it here: 
[apollo-server graphql-playground](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/graphql-playground.html)

if you want to enable it in production follow this guide:
[Enabling-GraphQL-Playground-in-production](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/graphql-playground.html#Enabling-GraphQL-Playground-in-production)